# Modern Splash Screen

Tags: c++, winapi

When you start up Microsoft Word, you know how there's that little unwindowed box that pops up for a second while everything loads?  How do I do that?  The `CreateWindow()`function has a `windowed` argument, but all it does when I send a `false` is make the window fullscreen.  Any ideas?

Reference material:

[CreateWindow function on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by "unwindowed box"? Do you mean a window without a title bar?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvc/thread/060d4e8b-48e1-4e26-9ee3-7142e48631a7 ?

Comment: Popup windows don't have the borders. I'm guessing that's the window style a splash screen uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to choose the proper [window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Don't set WS_BORDER or WS_CAPTION.

Comment: Perfect.  I got the answer I wanted so quickly, I wasn't even allowed to call it the answer until I was alread logged off.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good old CodeProject has some projects that do that, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15523/Own-thread-Win32-splash-screen for example.